# Can firefox restore a secure session after an add-on installation?

Tags: firefox-addon

When installing an add-on from a secure website (https) firefox installs the add on normally and requests the user to restart the browser. When the user clicks restart, the secure session is lost and they are forced to log in again. Is it possible to restore the secure session by simply retaining the secure session cookies in the case of an add-on restart?

Answer (score 1):

You want to set browser.sessionstore.privacy_level to 0.  See [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.sessionstore.privacy_level) for more details.