# Prevent Firefox from restoring session cookies after restart

Tags: firefox, session-cookies

Firefox has a feature to restore session cookies after restart (either after crash or if user has set "restore session" option) and that's causing a lot of problems (for example: [Firefox session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777767/firefox-session-cookies)).

However some sites, most notably Gmail, somehow don't have this problem. After it restores session Firefox won't sign you back in Gmail, you'll have to enter user/pass again. (although, I am not quite sure if Gmail uses session cookies at all)

Is there a way for server application "prevent" browser from restoring session cookies? Or is there some way to know that you are in restored session?

Comment: I think Gmail doesn't have the problem because Firefox doesn't restore https cookies by default (there is a preference for it though).

Comment: That occurred to me too after I posted the question. Haven't been able to test it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question...

According to [Can firefox restore a secure session after an add-on installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843491/can-firefox-restore-a-secure-session-after-an-add-on-installation) and the page it links to http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.sessionstore.privacy_level there's a Firefox setting 'browser.sessionstore.privacy_level' which determines what FF session restores saves (can be 0, 1 or 2 - see second link).

Until FF4 it was default to store/restore only non-secure sessions (that's why GMail currently asks you to sign in again - they are using SSL/HTTPS), but in FF4 default setting will be to store ALL sessions - so even secure sessions will be restored by FF.